# Varnish 6 not start after fresh install

Tags: varnish

I have install varnish 6 on Centos 7 based operating system, WHM/cPanel Installed and Apache and nGix are running where nGix is the Front and Apache is behind server, Apache run on port 8080.

here is the logs it shows when i try to start it and enable it:

```
[root@server ~]# systemctl status varnish.service
● varnish.service - Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-12-06 08:52:52 CET; 14min ago
  Process: 8478 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :6081 -a localhost:8443,PROXY -p feature=+http2 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -s malloc,256m (code=exited, status=255)
```

here is journal logs:

```
Dec 06 08:52:52 server.xxxx.xx systemd[1]: Starting Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator...
Dec 06 08:52:52 server.xxxx.xx varnishd[8478]: Error: -a arguments localhost:8443 and localhost:8443 have same address
Dec 06 08:52:52 server.xxxx.xx varnishd[8478]: (-? gives usage)
Dec 06 08:52:52 server.xxxx.xx systemd[1]: varnish.service: control process exited, code=exited status=255
Dec 06 08:52:52 server.xxxx.xx systemd[1]: Failed to start Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator.
Dec 06 08:52:52 server.xxxx.xx systemd[1]: Unit varnish.service entered failed state.
Dec 06 08:52:52 server.xxxx.xx systemd[1]: varnish.service failed.
```

i try to start it with debug mod to find out weather its conflict with any port or something but its start without any error, # varnishd -n foo -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -s malloc,1G -T 127.0.0.1:2000  -a 0.0.0.0:8080 -d

even in the debug mod its accept start command without showing any error.

here is file /usr/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator
After=network-online.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=forking
KillMode=process

# Maximum number of open files (for ulimit -n)
LimitNOFILE=131072

# Locked shared memory - should suffice to lock the shared memory log
# (varnishd -l argument)
# Default log size is 80MB vsl + 1M vsm + header -> 82MB
# unit is bytes
LimitMEMLOCK=85983232

# Enable this to avoid "fork failed" on reload.
TasksMax=infinity

# Maximum size of the corefile.
LimitCORE=infinity

ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd \
      -a :6081 \
      -a localhost:8443,PROXY \
      -p feature=+http2 \
      -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
      -s malloc,256m
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/varnishreload

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

any clue or help please ?

Comment: Please add the full content of `/usr/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service` to your question. The error indicates that the `-a` parameter was used twice with the same address details.

Comment: EDIT the file content

Comment: I cannot spot any issue in your configuration. However the error messages states that you're using `-a localhost:8443` more than once. Is there a way to check your systemd configuration or other runtime configurations for a `varnishd` process where the same address is assigned twice?

Comment: i removed localhost from localhost:8443 fix tihs issue, so now configuration is like ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd \
      -a :6081 \
      -a :8443,PROXY \
      -p feature=+http2 \
      -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
      -s malloc,256m
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/varnishreload